# Copyright of LaTex Templates?

Tags: copyright

I have a LaTeX template produced by Elsevier, "elsarticle-template-3-num.tex", which I have used to typeset a document. I want to distribute the compiled .pdf that I have typeset. Does the copyright of the template place any restrictions on my distribution of the compiled .pdf? Or does Elsevier have any say regarding the distribution of my typeset document?

To be explicit, here is the copyright statement in the header of the template:

```
%% This is file `elsarticle-template-3-num.tex',
%%
%% Copyright 2009 Elsevier Ltd
%%
%% This file is part of the 'Elsarticle Bundle'.
%% ---------------------------------------------
%%
%% It may be distributed under the conditions of the LaTeX Project Public
%% License, either version 1.2 of this license or (at your option) any
%% later version.  The latest version of this license is in
%%    http://www.latex-project.org/lppl.txt
%% and version 1.2 or later is part of all distributions of LaTeX
%% version 1999/12/01 or later.
%%
%% The list of all files belonging to the 'Elsarticle Bundle' is
%% given in the file `manifest.txt'.
%%
%% Template article for Elsevier's document class `elsarticle'
%% with numbered style bibliographic references
%%
%% $Id: elsarticle-template-3-num.tex 165 2009-10-08 07:58:10Z rishi $
%% $URL: http://lenova.river-valley.com/svn/elsbst/trunk/elsarticle-template-3-num.tex $
%%
```

I'm not sure if this is the appropriate place to ask this, but thought that the TeX community might have some experience or could point me to a resource/documentation that could answer the question.

Comment: Simple answer (to the distribution of the PDF question) is no.  See [Is a PDF output from a LaTeX document, a "derived work" from the LPPL standard packages?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/82713). (Effectively a duplicate, I think.)