# Publishing an article written in MiKTeX

Tags: miktex, arxiv, publishing

I have written an article in MiKTeX, and it seems that it *could* be published.

If I am gonna really publish this article of mine I should probably include in document some text which is (and maybe some which is not) seen when document is viewed in, for, example, Adobe Acrobat Reader, but, I do not know what should I include?

I do not know is this kind of question appropriate here but I really do not know what I need to include, because I have seen that there are some licences and laws and I do not know how strict they are.

So, suppose, for example, that I choose to publish an article of mine at arXiv.

What are the necessary (and sufficient?) steps to do that?

What kind of text should I include in my file so as to (if necessary) give credit or words of thanks to the author(s) of MiKTeX and to do everything according to existant laws and licences?

Where to include it and how?

You can understand that since this could be my first article and I am new in the world of TeX and TeX-related concepts that I do not know what are the strict rules and laws that must be obeyed, so right guidance is most welcomed.

Comment: I do not fully understand what you mean. MikTeX is a TeX distribution. Probably your article is written using the LaTeX markup language and compiled using e.g. pdflatex. LaTeX itself is a TeX format and TeX is a program written by Donald E. Knuth. Whom exactly do you want to thank? And what should this have to do with laws (which laws do you refer to)?

Comment: @TeXnician I am confused. I know that all that has to do with TeX is free and open, but I do not know what exactly is allowed and what is not. For example, when it comes to writing and publisihing an article.

Comment: It's refreshing to see some polite and humble Latex user who actually wants to thank the authors of MikTeX:) If you write something in MS Word, do you thank to Bill Gates or Office programmers? And unlike TeX, those are even not for free.

Comment: If you really want to acknowledge MikTex, here are some guidelines:
https://miktex.org/copying
"Finally, I make the following requests (not legal requirements):
a. Acknowledging that MiKTeX is developed as a joint effort by all TeX user groups, and encouraging the user/reader to join their user group of choice, as listed on the web page http://www.tug.org/usergroups.html.
b. Referencing the MiKTeX project page: https://miktex.org.

Such information may be placed on the label of your media, your cover, and/or in accompanying text (for instance, in the acknowledgements section of a book)."

Comment: Related : https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/82713/is-a-pdf-output-from-a-latex-document-a-derived-work-from-the-lppl-standard-p (related about opensource and our output of them... it is closed but I think the answer there will help you be less confused)