# Is it legal to sell pdf made in LaTeX?

Tags: licensing

I know that using LaTex is free, but is selling pdf made in LaTeX legal?

I looked up the license https://www.latex-project.org/lppl/ , but got nowhere to reading, "Selling pdf made in LaTeX is legal".

Is there something I missed?

Edit: And also copyrighting pdf made in LaTeX is legal?

Comment: We cannot give any legal advice. Your question is off-topic.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/82713/35864

Comment: @frougan I'm not really sure, but the answer writes, "...and the output is not under any license but under whatever license you would put that output." and I interpret this statement as, "You can copyright the pdf (which also mean you can sell it.)". This is my hunch.

Comment: What you copyright is your intellectual work, and this is also what you sell to people. The content. What people do with the pdf is pretty much out of your way.